# How to point to other GMail accounts/folders in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

`var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,10)`

will fetch ten threads from **my** main work email inbox.  But I also have access to several mailbox accounts for my department in my company.

I would like to write a google apps script that will cycle through an inbox or other folder in one of these mailboxes' accounts.  Could someone please point me in the right direction on how I would get the GmailApp class to point to a different email account instead of my main inbox?

I have looked through the online documentation and done searches and have not found anything that describes how to point the GmailApp class to another email account.

Comment: How do you have access to the other mailboxes? Also, are you working with Gmail accounts or Google Workspace accounts.

Comment: I access the accounts by clicking on my little google account rectangle in the top-right of my gmail and a dropdown appears of all of the other email accounts I have access to. To the right of each account it says _delegated_. 

This is a corporate account. My company uses gmail/gsuite instead of Outlook/MS Office. So I assume that this is a "workspace" account???

I found the GMail API and there appears to the a **users** collection or array which has

    GET https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{id}

but I don't know how to use that.

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75621016/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Hey @GregTruby I just implemented Lorena's answer and it worked for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has reponded.  I'm still working with my company's I/T department to see if I can implement this or some other solution they can develop.  Hopefully I will be able to post some results soon!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you're trying to retrieve ten threads from other inbox accounts. Even though you have access to other users inbox as a delegate, to access the delegated accounts inbox data with the API, you need to authenticate as that specific user. There is a way to do this programmatically in Apps Script but this alternative works for Google Workspace accounts and you need administrator role to configure certain things in the Google Workspace Admin console.

For this you can use a Google Service account with domain-wide delegation and the email address of the user you are trying to impersonate.

You can use the following sample code, I used [this](https://www.labnol.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script) as a reference and it works.

```
var JSON = {
  private_key: 'private_key',
  client_email: 'client_email',
  client_id: 'client_id',
  user_email: 'email_address_of_user_to_impersonate',
};

function getOAuthService(user) {
  return OAuth2.createService('Service Account')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setPrivateKey(JSON.private_key)
    .setIssuer(JSON.client_email)
    .setSubject(JSON.user_email)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setScope('https://mail.google.com/');
}

function getUserThreads() {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();
    var url = 'https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/'+JSON.user_email+'/threads?maxResults=10';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      },
    });
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function reset() {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  service.reset();
}
```

**Note:** You need to add the [OAuth2 Library](https://morioh.com/p/5f9072920503) to your Apps Script project.

**References:**

- [Create a service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726)
- [Manage Domain Wide Delegation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?#zippy=%2Cbefore-you-begin%2Cset-up-domain-wide-delegation-for-a-client)
- [Method: users.threads.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/list)